# Why is this function not returning a char data type?

Tags: c, primes, return-type, string-literals, function-definition

//Prime function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
char Premier(int N){
    int i;
    char notpremier="Nombre n'est pas premier"; //Number is prime
    char premier="Nombre est premier"; //Number isn't prime
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(N);i++){
        if(N % i==0){
            return notpremier;
        }
        else{
            return premier;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    printf("%c",Premier(10));
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I choose to return an int data type, it works perfectly.

Comment: `char` is a single character, like `'N'`. You cannot assign a string to a `char`.

Comment: This: `"Nombre n'est pas premier" `is a string and not a `char`so it can't be assigned to `char`variable.

Comment: It's a good idea to enable as many warnings as you can. Here you should get one about converting a pointer to an int without cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function returns nothing if the user will pass a value less than 4.

Secondly you are trying to initialize objects of the type `char` with expressions of the type `char *` because the string literals used as right hand operands are converted implicitly to pointers.

Also the comments are invalid.

```
char notpremier="Nombre n'est pas premier"; //Number is prime
char premier="Nombre est premier"; //Number isn't prime
```

And you have to move the sub-statement of the else statement

```
    else{
        return premier;
    }
```

below the for loop.

At least you need to write

```
char * Premier(int N){
```

and

```
char * notpremier="Nombre n'est pas premier"; //Number isn't prime
char * premier="Nombre est premier"; //Number is prime
```

and

```
for(i=2;i<=sqrt(N);i++){
    if(N % i==0){
        return notpremier;
    }
}

return premier;
```

But also take into account that `0` and `1` are not prime numbers.
And the function parameter should have unsigned integer type as for example `unsigned int` instead of the signed integer type `int`.

And instead of returning a string literal the function should return an integer: 1 - the passed number is prime, 0 - the passed number is not prime.